# error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/boot.mod' not found. On Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: grubrescue

I'm getting this error over Ubuntu 16.04 on startup.im not able to start my pc.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything else on the screen? If so, what?

Comment: No nothing. Just grub rescue terminal is open.